# VBA script to conditionally format specific text in a concatenated cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to Excel and trying to write a VBA script to conditionally format some cells.

I have Column A each individual cell looks like this.

> Project Name: Name One
>   AO: Name Two
>   BO: Name Three
>   CO: Name Four
>   DO: Name Five

One extra detail is that not every cell has all five lines. For example a cell might only have:

> AO: Name Two
>   BO: Name Three

What I need to do is to format it so that Project Name:, AO:, BO:, CO:, and DO: are all bolded while Name One is bolded, italicized and coloured. I can't tell how to add colour here but it would look something like this.

> **Project Name:** ***Name One (with colour)***
>   **AO:** Name Two
>   **BO:** Name Three
>   **CO:** Name Four
>   **DO:** Name Five

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a VBA script to do this automatically? My workaround the past few days has been individually selecting text in each cell and applying the formatting there, and it has been hell!

Excel version: 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

This pair of subroutines will do the job.  The formatting can be applied to a range of cells at once.

```
' Make a keyboard shortcut for this macro:
Sub FormatActiveCells()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        FormatCell c
    Next
End Sub

' This subroutine does the work
Sub FormatCell(c As Range)
    Dim pos1 As Integer, pos2 As Integer
    ' Determine if line 1 is project name
    pos1 = InStr(1, c.Text, "Project Name:")
    If pos1 > 0 Then
        ' Make "Project Name:" bold
        c.Characters(pos1, Len("Project Name:")).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        ' Advance past colon character
        pos1 = pos1 + Len("Project Name:")
        ' Find end-of-line character
        pos2 = InStr(pos1, c.Text, Chr(10))
        ' Make text between "Project Name:" and end-line italicized and colored
        c.Characters(pos1, pos2 - pos1).Font.FontStyle = "Bold Italic"
        c.Characters(pos1, pos2 - pos1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        ' Point both positions to one character past end-of-line
        pos2 = pos2 + 1
        pos1 = pos2
    Else
        ' Point both positions to first character
        pos1 = 1
        pos2 = 1
    End If

    ' Format additional lines
    Do
        ' Find colon character
        pos2 = InStr(pos1, c.Text, ":")
        ' If not found, we're done
        If pos2 = 0 Then Exit Do
        ' Make text from start of line to colon bold
        c.Characters(Start:=pos1, Length:=pos2 - pos1).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        ' Find end-of-line
        pos2 = InStr(pos2 + 1, c.Text, Chr(10))
        ' If not found, we're done
        If pos2 = 0 Then Exit Do
        ' Point both positions to one character past end-of-line
        pos2 = pos2 + 1
        pos1 = pos2
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This works fantastic for lines 2-4, but on the first line I actually would want only "Name One" to be italicized and coloured (in addition to bolding for the whole line). Also, I was hoping for something that would react accordingly to missing lines - say, the entire first line wasn't there and the cell started off with "AO: etc etc". I wouldn't want AO to be coloured/italicized

Comment: I made my own bloated macro to do it last night but this one is simpler, smarter and works like a dream. Many thanks, sir.